# How do I start a tcplistener on a domain name?

Tags: c#

I have the problem that my tcplistener only gets requests when specifying the actual IP in the browser, but I want to be able to call it by computer name as well.

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5556);
listener.Start();
```

visit this in browser:

http://mycomputername.com:5556/

but it doesnt work. I got my computer name by "nslookup [myip]"

Comment: Do you need to remove. ".com" part of the address?

Comment: thanks for the tip! No, but the full computer name works fine from localhost, I only ever tried it from the vm. Has to be some kind of networking issue maybe, not sure how to proceed. I can access from IP from the virtual machine

Comment: This is a DNS/networking issue, not a programming issue. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running your own internal DNS server the "mycomputername.com" url is going to get resolved by an external DNS server, which will return the external (internet facing) IP address.  You will need to configure your router(s) to forward the correct port (tcp:5556) from the internet facing side of your network to the correct internal computer.  This is usually in the "NAT", or "Firewall" section of your router's configuration.